# Why does iverilog generate a syntax error for always_ff?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I recently started System Verilog and I'm a bit dumbfounded by a syntax error. Given the following module:

test.sv :

```
module test(
  input logic clk,  
  output logic out );

  always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    out = 1'b1;
  end
endmodule
```

When compiling with `iverilog -g2012 test.sv`, a simple `syntax-error` for line 5 (always_ff) is generated. I don't know why this happens since my syntax seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct for SystemVerilog, but it is not supported for all `iverilog` versions. From the [Release Notes of Icarus Verilog 11](https://iverilog.fandom.com/wiki/Release_Notes_Icarus_Verilog_11)

> The following SystemVerilog language features are now supported:
>
> the always_comb, **always_ff**, and always_latch constructs

If you are not using this version, you should upgrade.

Your code compiles on other simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/es2D).

Alternately, you don't need to use `always_ff`.  You can still use `always`:

```
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    out <= 1'b1;
  end
```

---

I changed your assignment to nonblocking (`<=`), which is recommended for sequential logic.